# Using pgfplotstable to convert a .csv to a table but doesn't like the ∞ symbol

Tags: pgfplotstable

Here's my .tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % allows use of numberless equation* package
\usepackage{fullpage} % uses more of the page
\usepackage{graphicx} % allows use of pictures
\usepackage{float} % better image positioning
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Generates table from .csv
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\title{TMA xx}
\date{2020-xx-xx}
\author{Ben Jones}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \subsection*{Question 1}    
    Question (if necessary)
        \paragraph{a)}
        Answer
            \begin{equation*}
            f(x)=2x^2
            \end{equation*}
        \paragraph{b)}
        Answer
        \begin{table}[h!]
            \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                col sep=&, 
            ]{test.csv}
            \end{center}
        \end{table}
    \newline
    \newline
    \subsection*{Question 2}
    Question (if necessary)
        \paragraph{a)}
        Answer
            \begin{equation*}
            f(x)=2x^2
            \end{equation*}
        \paragraph{b)}
        Answer
            \begin{figure}[h!]
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{graph.png}
                \caption{A thing.}
                \label{fig:thing1}
            \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the test.csv file:

```
    x & (-∞, 2)
    1 & 2
```

The build LOg in Gummi shows this error:

```
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
/home/ben/Documents/BSc_Computing/MST124_Essential_Maths/LaTeX_Files/.TMA_Templ
ate.tex.swp:30: Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.30            ]{test.csv}
                   ^^M
```

Removing the infinity symbol from the .csv removes the error and lets the file compile, but I want the symbol in the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Does adding `text special chars={∞}` to the options of `\pgfplotstabletypeset` help?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat tried that and the error it gives is undefined control seqence, even if the .csv file contains no infinity symbol.